# Deleting new line when beginning new theorem in a list

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate, amsthm

I am using the package `amsthm` to type my assignments and I have encountered the following problem. Here's the code I use:

```
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
:
:
\begin{enumerate} 

\item
\begin{claim}
    $lefthalf(L) := \{w_1 :  \exists w_2 \in \Sigma^*.w_1w_2 \in L.|w_1| = |w_2|\}$.
\end{claim}

\item 
{\textbf{Claim 1.}} $lefthalf(L) := \{w_1 :  \exists w_2 \in \Sigma^*.w_1w_2 \in L.|w_1| = |w_2|\}$.

\end{enumerate}
```

This gives the following result:

[image: New line problem while using newthm in lists]

As you can see in (a), the claim begins on the second line. I would like my claim to be as in (b) where I simulate the style I want. Is there any way I could get rid of this extra newline occuring when I use `newthm` in a list? I have tried to change `theoremstyle` but couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to remove line breaks before and after theorems?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77901/35864). Note that it is not best practice to use an `enumerate` and then a theorem-like environment, the latter has a counter already `(a) Claim 1` seems somewhat redundant. It would be better to drop the `enumerate` or not to use the `claim` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Don't add text to the automatically added comment for a “possible duplicate”, because the comment will be removed by the system if the question is actually marked as duplicate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you should use `\mathit{lefthalf}` for a multiletter variable or function name.

Comment: @egreg I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/why-was-possible-duplicate-comment-with-additional-information-deleted