# An inline exercise environment

Tags: numbering, environments, exercises

In my lecture notes I want to leave some work as exercises and plan to give solutions later in the text. For example,

> "The proof of this theorem is left as an exercise (Exercise 1.2)".

It must also have a label so that it could be referred later. I think I need an inline exercise environment.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77898/how-to-remove-line-breaks-before-and-after-theorems) answers my question. In the last answer in this post Werner has proposed that it could done in a better way may be with macros. I have too many of them so would be very difficult to do it with `\lipsum \begin \end` every single time. Can this be done with a single command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an implementation that provides a `\exinline` command, taking a label argument to produce the relevant text.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newcommand{\exinline}[1]{(\refstepcounter{theorem}Exercise~\thetheorem\label{#1})}

\begin{document}

\section{Euler's Theorem}

Some text.

\begin{theorem}[Euler]
  \label{thm:Euler}
  This is Euler's theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  The proof of this theorem is left as an exercise \exinline{ex:Euler}.
\end{proof}

\begin{exercise}
  \label{ex:extra}
  Reformulate the theorem.
\end{exercise}

Here is the solution to Exercise~\ref{ex:Euler}.  By\dots

Note that Exercise~\ref{ex:extra} requires you to provide another formulation
of Theorem~\ref{thm:Euler}.

\end{document}
```

Note in this example Exercises and Theorems share the same counter.  If that is not the case, you need to replace the `theorem` counter in definition with the appropriate counter, and change `\thetheorem` correspondingly.  E.g. if exercises have their own number, declared
via `\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]`, the command definition should read

```
\newcommand{\exinline}[1]{(\refstepcounter{exercise}Exercise~\theexercise\label{#1})}
```

If you are using `cleveref` for references then a small modification is needed to the `refstepcounter` command so `\cref` picks up the correct name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newcommand{\exinline}[1]{(\refstepcounter[exercise]{theorem}Exercise~\thetheorem\label{#1})}

\begin{document}

\section{Euler's Theorem}

Some text.

\begin{theorem}[Euler]
  \label{thm:Euler}
  This is Euler's theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  The proof of this theorem is left as an exercise \exinline{ex:Euler}.
\end{proof}

\begin{exercise}
  \label{ex:extra}
  Reformulate the theorem.
\end{exercise}

Here is the solution to \cref{ex:Euler}.  By\dots

Note that \cref{ex:extra} requires you to provide another formulation
of \cref{thm:Euler}.

\end{document}
```

This produces the same output as the first example, with `cleveref` correctly providing the names.